# Pointer to interface with saving type

Tags: pointers, go, interface

The shortest way to explain my problem is [that code](http://play.golang.org/p/cTZYcz_1BX):

```
var i interface{} // I can't change it. In fact this is a function,
i = Item{10}      // that receives interface{}, that contain object (not pointer to object!)

fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", i, i)
// fmt.Println(i.(NextValuer).NextVal())  // won't compile
i = &i
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", i, i)               // there i is pointer to interface{} (not to Item)
// fmt.Println(i.(NextValuer).NextVal())  // panics
// fmt.Println(i.(*NextValuer).NextVal()) // won't compile
```

But if I try to set pointer to Item to i, code works:

```
i = &Item{10}
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", i, i)
fmt.Println(i.(NextValuer).NextVal())
```

But my function receives object, not pointer to it. And I can get type of it (first `fmt.Printf`). But when I try to make pointer to it, I receive pointer to `interface{}`, not to my Object (`Item`).

Can I make pointer to this object to call `NextVal`? Or may be other ways to do it

Comment: This line makes no sense: `i = &i`

Comment: May be. But first two lines in `stdout` differ

Comment: Maybe the best advice here might be: Stop shaving the yak and redesign everything from scratch. NextValuer smells like forcing iterators on Go. If some thing just returns one thing after the other endlessly why not use a channel?

Comment: @Volker it is just a short version to show a problem. the real code is bigger and complicated

Comment: Then redesigning it seems even more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use a pointer to an interface. If you need a pointer to call a method with a pointer receiver, a pointer is what you must put into the `interface{}`.

If you have already have value in an `interface{}` where you want to call a method with a pointer receiver, you need to make an addressable copy of that value.

What you're trying to accomplish with `i = &i` is probably:

```
item := i.(Item)
i = &item
```

This creates an addressable copy of the original `Item`, and then puts a pointer to that copy into `i`. Note that this can never change the value of the original `Item`.

If you don't know the type that can be in the `interface{}`, you can make a copy of the value with "reflect":

```
func nextVal(i interface{}) {
    // get the value in i
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)

    // create a pointer to a new value of the same type as i
    n := reflect.New(v.Type())
    // set the new value with the value of i
    n.Elem().Set(v)

    // Get the new pointer as an interface, and call NextVal
    fmt.Println("NextVal:", n.Interface().(NextValuer).NextVal())

    // this could also be assigned another interface{}
    i = n.Interface()
    nv, ok := i.(NextValuer)
    fmt.Printf("i is a NextValuer: %t\nNextVal: %d\n", ok, nv.NextVal())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/gbO9QGz2Tq

Comment: No, I can't do it. Because I have many types, that implements `NextValuer`

Comment: @AlikSend: what do you mean "no, you can't do it"? You either need to start with a pointer (which is what you should be doing), or create a copy to get a pointer, there aren't any other choices. Do you want a solution which uses reflect to create a new copy of the value?

Comment: @JimBe I just coming up with an idea to make it, but with that I have to change code in whole project. If it can be done with `reflect`, can you show me that? That decision because I already use `reflect` in this function

Comment: @AlikSend: Added a reflect example for when you have absolutely no idea what type the interface may contain, and you need a pointer instead of a value.

Comment: I mark your answer as solution. But I think that redesigning is really be better in this case. Thank you