# How can I add elements to slice reflection?

Tags: arrays, go, insert, append

Hi i am learning `Go` and i was doing some reflection. I got stuck in a case like this:

1. I want to create a `slice` of `struct` passed to function as `interface{}`
2. Then I want to append new elements to this slice

Here is a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Kmbw5_Oine) with the code example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct{ Name string }

func main() {
    bbb(A{})
}

func aaa(v interface{}) {
    sl := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
    typeOfT := sl.Type()

    ptr := reflect.New(typeOfT).Interface()
    s := reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Elem()
    sl.Set(reflect.Append(sl, s))

    ptr = reflect.New(typeOfT).Interface()
    s = reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Elem()
    sl.Set(reflect.Append(sl, s))
}

func bbb(v interface{}) {
    myType := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    models := reflect.Zero(reflect.SliceOf(myType)).Interface()
    aaa(&models)

    fmt.Println(models)
}
```

**Error:** `panic: reflect: call of reflect.Append on interface Value`

Is there a way to make it work ? 
Note: that i want to work on a reference.

**Solution:**

Here is what i manage to do: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3mIEFqMxk-).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600817/pointer-to-interface-with-saving-type/34600906 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713749/unmarshal-into-array-of-structs-determined-at-runtime-in-go/37713982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `reflect.Zero` when i created slie with `reflect.New` it worked. Here you have full working example.

https://play.golang.org/p/3mIEFqMxk-

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Name string `column:"email"`
}

func main() {
    bbb(&A{})
}

func aaa(v interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        t = t.Elem()
    } else {
        panic("Input param is not a slice")
    }

    sl := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        sl = sl.Elem()
    }

    st := sl.Type()
    fmt.Printf("Slice Type %s:\n", st)

    sliceType := st.Elem()
    if sliceType.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        sliceType = sliceType.Elem()
    }
    fmt.Printf("Slice Elem Type %v:\n", sliceType)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        newitem := reflect.New(sliceType)
        newitem.Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString(fmt.Sprintf("Grzes %d", i))

        s := newitem.Elem()
        for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
            col := s.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("column")
            fmt.Println(col, s.Field(i).Addr().Interface())
        }

        sl.Set(reflect.Append(sl, newitem))
    }
}

func bbb(v interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("Input param is not a struct")
    }

    models := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(v))).Interface()

    aaa(models)

    fmt.Println(models)

    b, err := json.Marshal(models)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/sc7iBknOAd))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct{ Name string }

func main() {
    bbb(A{})
}

func aaa(v interface{}) interface{} {
    sl := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    typeOfT := sl.Type().Elem()

    ptr := reflect.New(typeOfT).Interface()
    s := reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Elem()
    return reflect.Append(sl, s)
}

func bbb(v interface{}) {
    myType := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    models := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(myType), 0, 1).Interface()
    fmt.Println(aaa(models))
}
```

Note that I'm returning the new slice. I think you'd need another layer of indirection (pointer to a pointer) to do this without a return value, but this was my first time doing reflection in Go, so I may be going about things all wrong.

Comment: but the point is i dont want to return a new object i want to work on a reference, as many packages do like json encode/decode or sql scan etc etc

Comment: @Vardius: you're not starting with a pointer, so you have to make new one somewhere. Passing a pointer to an interface doesn't get you a pointer to your value.

Comment: @JimB I have updated my question with my progress so far

Comment: if you are curious i added solution link to playground i managed to do